# Create re-usable form objects in C#

Tags: c#, forms

How do you create a re-usable objects in c# forms? As an example, a custom item in a form-list that shows an image, and some individual text blocks? A contacts list as an example.

Comment: You're looking for either classes or user controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the windows forms usercontrol class: [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). If you create an usercontrol, you can reuse it and embedd it everywhere you need it. You could also create some custom controls by deriving from other controls, such as `ListBoxItem` or some thing else (e.g. `Form`, ...).